# How to check if using the correct API level in Android

Tags: java, android, api

I have an Android App with:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

So mainly it uses the api lvl 7 and at some points it checks the device's version and uses some methods of higher API.

The problem is that the eclipse autocomplete suggests methods of api lvl 14 so in a large program is posible to use a method with level 8+ by mistake.

Is there a technique for avoiding that?

Thanks

Comment: Develop with Android SDK  Library at Level 7  or 2.1 .  That will ensure all the compatibility. Once you set a minimum , that's what you have to use. :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can get what you want by changing the project properties, which as been set to the default values when you created the project. So don't change your Manifest file, but select Project->Properties->Android->"Porject Build Target" and select a target with level 7. That way you should get auto-completion for level7, but keep your manifest targetSdkVersion property to 14.
Additionally, it's probably a good idea to have two virtual devices to test the different behaviors.

Alexis

Answer (score 3):

I agree with ngen every once and a while change your targetSdkVersion to 7 and see what pops up.  Also during development you can usually hover over a method and see its "Since" for form what API level it is valid (see image blow)

[image: Since API Level]